# Can i use Google Oboe or AAudio in iOS ? https://github.com/google/oboe

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, oboe

I want to use C++ library which makes it easy to build high-performance audio apps

https://github.com/google/oboe

Google Oboe seems for Android
can i somehow use it for iOS also ? or any similar alternative for iOS ?

I don't want to use Superpowered because of their licence terms!

Answer (score 4):

There are no plans to release an iOS version of Oboe at present. You could look at FMOD or JUCE.

Comment: Thanks @donturner 
How about PortAudio ? can it be built for iOS (iPhone OS)

Comment: I have no idea I'm afraid. A brief look at the website doesn't mention iOS so I would assume not.

Comment: Thanks @donturner
Is it possible to build it for iOS ? if its supports MacOS. they use mostly same coreAudio if i am not wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly (from videos of demos at events), The development of this library came from people heavily involved with the Google Android infrastructure, and thus the Oboe library is highly customized to tackle the low-latency short-comings of Android.

This being said, Google would not have the resources to tackle such an intensive and complicated problem for a completely different platform.  As well (unfortunately) that wouldn't be in their best interest competitively-speaking.

I have heard of others using Superpowered, but I haven't gotten much info on it honestly, their marketing about it is all fluff, and there isn't any actual useful information, haha.  I used Oboe myself, because I needed a dedicated native library.

As for iOS, I found a decent blog page that might be worth checking out: https://exceed7.com/native-audio/

This page suggests using OpenAL for objective-C/Swift.  It looks like OpenAL is the similar implementation to OpenSL, which the Oboe library is partially based on.  Unity seems to also utilize a library called FMOD (Not familiar with this one myself), as well DonTurner mentioned JUCE?.

So perhaps looking into these would be a good start, although I would assume using OpenAL might have some pretty involved developing, so ready your thinking cap!

Best of luck on your project!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for AudioKit

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit